# Show a dialog with dynamically loaded HTML content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, dialog

I want to display a dialog which contains HTML that is dynamically generated:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://localhost/example/test",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (content) {
            $(content).dialog();
        }
    });
```

`content` is basically a complete HTML site with header and body. If I change `$(content).dialog()` to `alert(content)` the generated HTML is displayed correctly. But `content.dialog()` throws the following exception on Firefox 5:

```
a.style is undefined 
Source: http://localhost/TrackerWebStable/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
Line: 150
```

I've also tested it with IE8 where I get similar errors.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` will contain the entire html markup. I believe you want to show some part of it in a dialog. Try to find the required element from the whole html and show it in a dialog.

Alternatively, you can only send the required markup from `"http://localhost/example/test` so that you dont have to find anything in the success handler but just show it in the dialog.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://localhost/example/test",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (content) {
            $(content).find("requiredElement").dialog();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I would prefer to show the whole markup as a dialog. Is that not possible?

Comment: I solved it without the full HTML page, so the question is no longer relevant.